# Regex Regular Expression - Only include numbers in result

Tags: regex, zapier

I am trying to extract only the numbers after a specific string `Total (ex. VAT)    £112.49`. I have started learning regex today and getting stuck. I have got it returning the value I want but it is also showing some letters also.

[image]

Here is the regex query: `ex.*?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Here is the data:

```
Sub total (inc. VAT)    £134.99
VAT £22.50
Total (inc. VAT)    £134.99
Total (ex. VAT) £112.49:
```

- **Result:** `ex. VAT) £112.49`
- **Desired Result:** `112.49`

I have also attached a screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a capture group and make the pattern a bitmore specific:

```
\(ex\.[^()]*\)\s*£(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `ex\.` Match `ex.`
- `[^()]*` Match optional chars other than `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `£` Match literally
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` Group 1, 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w01BQ6/1)

Or use `\D*` to match optional non digits before capturing the digits:

```
\(ex\.[^()]*\)\s*\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hilD7F/1)

Comment: Thats working perfectly thank you for your help.

I am also trying to find "A12364721035" from "Order number: A12364721035"
&
"8840" from "Your ref: 8840"

I was hoping I would be able to edit the formula accordingly but it isnt behaving as I expected. Can I ask for your help on this also?

Comment: why don't you prefer to use `(\d+.\d+)` instead of `(?:\.\d+)`?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Because `(\d+.\d+)` matches at least 3 characters, being 1 or more leading digits, then a single character except a newline, and then again 1 or more digits.

Comment: @Zezima_original For the other 2 patterns you can also use a capture group `\bOrder number:\s*([A-Z]\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/hGBWJJ/1 and `\bYour ref:\s*(\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/egUceR/1

Comment: Thank you so much I have used `\bOrder number:\s*([A-Z]\d+)\b` and  `\bYour ref:\s*(\d+)\b` as I dont trust my own format! Thanks for your help. both working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the static text you're looking to match, and utilize a pattern for the number.

Additionally, you'll want to place the value you're looking to capture, within a *[capture group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)*—also referred to as a *sub-expression*.

> *"I am trying to extract only the numbers after a specific string `Total (ex. VAT)    £112.49`."*

```
Total \(ex\. VAT\) +£(\d+\.\d+)
```

Group 1 will return the following.

```
112.49
```